# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure inventory, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 2] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Where'

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I fix this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure inventory, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Where'

This is my code

```
create view inventory ([name], [description], [price])
as 
    Select
        name, description, MaxPrice
    From
        item
    Join 
        ITEM_TYPE 
    Where
        item_id not in (Select itemid
                        From ORDER_ITEM
                        Where itemid not in (Select ItemID
                                             From ITEM_DONATION
                                             Where itemid not in (Select itemid
                                                                  From item pickup)))
Go
```

Comment: You are missing an `on` clause for your `join`.

Comment: Also, having 3 nested sub-queries seems a bit much. Maybe you could simplify using additional joins...

Comment: use aliases for table names!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the join condition between your tables:

```
create view inventory
  (
    [name]
  , [description]
  , [price]
  )
  as
Select
  name
, description
, MaxPrice
From
  item
  join
    ITEM_TYPE
    on item.<YOUR_FIELD>=ITEM_TYPE.<YOUR_FIELD>
Where
  item_id not in
  (
    Select
      itemid
    From
      ORDER_ITEM
    Where
      itemid not in
      (
        Select
          ItemID
        From
          ITEM_DONATION
        Where
          itemid not in
          (
            Select
              itemid
            From
              item pickup
          )
      )
  )
  Go
```

Answer (score 0):

> From item pickup)))

If there is a space in the table name item pickup, which is not best practice, then you need to surround the name in square brackets [item pickup].

And to expand on jaime's post, it would also help to use table aliases to define the tables, and used them in columns, so if there are columns in both tables with the same name then SQL Server knows which table_name.column_name you are referring to.